# Android textFontWeight api level less than 28

Tags: android, android-styles

I have a style resource for textView

```
<style name="AppText.Note.Medium">
    <item name="android:textFontWeight" tools:targetApi="p">500</item>
</style>
```

But it works on API level 28 or higher. Is there any way to use it on API level 23? Or maybe there is some alternative?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55693021/5416954 check this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Support font family on API lower than 26 use

```
  <item name="fontWeight">500</item>
```

Comment: Attribute fontWeight is only used in API level 26 and higher (current min is 21)

Comment: @FreePhoenix Use `app:fontWeight="500"` instead of `android:fontWeight="500"`

Comment: @Dinesh nothing changes when you set it, only `android:textFontWeight` makes effect but it's for API 28+

Answer (score 1):

This works on All api level

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        app:font="@font/sdfglay_bold"
        app:fontWeight="700"/>
    <font
        app:font="@font/sdfglay_light"
        app:fontWeight="300"/>
    <font
        app:font="@font/sdfglay_regular"
        app:fontWeight="400"/>
    <font
        app:font="@font/sdfglay_medium"
        app:fontWeight="500"/>
    <font
        app:font="@font/sdfglay_semibold"
        app:fontWeight="600"/>
```

instaed of this font familily

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/postDesc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sdfglay_light"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingVertical="8dp"/>
```

Use the font with spcifed weight diriectly

```
        android:fontFamily="@font/sdfglay_light"
```